# Mostrar consulta mysql de varias columnas en android

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

Necesito mostrar en android los datos que obtengo de una consulta con mysql pero la misma me dará como resultado varias columnas, dado que en android no hay algo semejante al JTable me preguntaba como se podría mostrar la información obtenida por dicha consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo muy básico usando `GridView` con 2 columnas:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</GridView>
```

Pásate por [este](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/) y este [otro tutorial(en este último usan TableLayout...)](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/table-layout-in-android.html)

Ánimo :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, esto podría servir para la disposición de los componentes si yo supiera cuantos son, el problema es que al ser de sql las filas aumentan o disminuyen, ñas columnas si son constantes, en primer lugar pensé en crear textviews en tiempo de ejecución mediante la consulta, un textview por cada resultado pero eso resulta muy enmarañado, al final logre lo que quería o semejante usando varios listview y sincronizando sus scroll para que se muevan como una unidad.

Answer (score 0):

Googleando un poco encontre que puedes usar GridView, te podria servir para lo que quieres hacer. Aca un link de referencia.
[GridView](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/interfaz-de-usuario-en-android-controles-de-seleccion-iv/)